# Capture exit code of exit command

Tags: bash, shell-script, exec, exit, exit-status

I have this in a bash script:

```
exit 3;

exit_code="$?"

if [[ "$exit_code" != "0" ]]; then
    echo -e "${r2g_magenta}Your r2g process is exiting with code $exit_code.${r2g_no_color}";
    exit "$exit_code";
fi
```

It looks like it will exit right after the exit command, which makes sense.
I was wondering is there some simple command that can provide an exit code without exiting right away?

I was going to guess:

```
exec exit 3
```

but it gives an error message: `exec: exit: not found`. 
What can I do? :)

Comment: Yeah `exec exit 3` is no bueno, I get `"exec: exit: not found"`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why not set `exit_code=3` and eliminate the `exit 3` line altogether?

Comment: @wjandrea is more a conceptual question than practical

Comment: It still makes no sense to me. Why would there be an exit code if you don't actually exit?

Comment: @Barmar every process has an exit code. Most of the people trying to answer the question are interpreting the question to mean "what can I replace the 'exit 3' with in the script so it sets the `$?` variable but doesn't exit *this* script"?

Comment: @icarus Oh, got it, OP is asking how to set `$?`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have a script that runs some program
and looks at the program's exit status (with `$?`),
and you want to test that script by doing *something*
that causes `$?` to be set to some known value (e.g., `3`), just do

```
(exit 3)
```

The parentheses create a sub-shell. 
Then the `exit` command causes that sub-shell
to exit with the specified exit status.

Comment: Also, for debugging purposes it'd be just as simple to set `exit_code="3"` for testing

Comment: Yes, [wjandrea pointed that out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/486902/80216#comment893257_486902) yesterday.

Answer (score 12):

`exit` is a bash built-in, so you can't `exec` it. Per [bash's manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Bash's exit status is the exit status of the last command executed in the script. If no commands are executed, the exit status is 0.

Putting all this together, I'd say your only option is to store your desired exit status in a variable and then `exit $MY_EXIT_STATUS` when appropriate.

Comment: hmmm what do you think about @G-man's idea?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to accomplish. If you're just trying to set `$?` (though I'm not really sure why you would), that does seem like a solid answer. If you just want to set it to some unsuccessful value, `false` is another option.

Answer (score 10):

You can write a function that returns the status given as argument, or `255` if none given. (I call it `ret` as it "returns" its value.)

```
ret() { return "${1:-255}"; }
```

and use `ret` in place of your call to `exit`. This is avoids the inefficiency of creating the sub-shell in the currently accepted answer.

Some measurements.

```
time bash -c 'for i in {1..10000} ; do (exit 3) ; done ; echo $?'
```

on my machine takes about 3.5 seconds.

```
 time bash -c 'ret(){ return $1 ; } ; for i in {1..10000} ; do ret 3 ; done ; echo $?'
```

on my machine takes about 0.051 seconds, 70 times faster. Putting in the default handling still leaves it 60 times faster. Obviously the loop has some overhead. If I change the body of the loop to just be `:` or `true` then the time is halved to 0.025, a completely empty loop is invalid syntax. Adding `;:` to the loop shows that this minimal command takes 0.007 seconds, so the loop overhead is about 0.018. Subtracting this overhead from the two tests shows that the `ret` solution is over 100 times faster.

Obviously this is a synthetic measurement, but things add up. If you make everything 100 times slower than they need to be then you end up with slow systems.
 0.0

Comment: @iBug The extra space is not needed.

Comment: Good point about the inefficiency of creating the sub-shell.  I've read that some shells might be smart enough to optimize the fork out in cases like this, but that bash isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3):

About `exec exit 3`... it would try to run an external command called `exit`, but there isn't one, so you get the error. It has to be an external command instead of one built in to the shell, since `exec` *replaces* the shell completely. Which also means that even if you had an external command called `exit`, `exec exit 3` would not return to continue your shell script, since *the shell wouldn't be there any more*.

Comment: I guess you could do `exec bash -c "exit 3"`, but at the moment I can't think of any reason to do that as opposed to just `exit 3`.

Comment: @DavidZ, in any case, `exec`'ing or just `exit`'ing will stop the script, which didn't seem like what the question wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{exit 9}'
```

Or Sed:

```
sed Q9 /proc/stat
```

Comment: ...or with a shell: `sh -c 'exit 9'`

Comment: @ilkkachu if youre going to do that you might as well do the `(exit 9)` in the accepted answer